# Docker, NodeJs, Vuejs : can't access with localhost

Tags: node.js, windows, vue.js, docker-compose, localhost

I try to run my local vue application with docker but it seem that i can't acces it with the localhost, i read that it's a windows problem but i can't solve it. i'm new in host problem and docker, i didn't success to apply the solution.

When I run

```
docker-compose up
```

Everything seem to be good, my backend is correctly connected to my database, my vue application is running, but when try too access it localy, i have an 404 error.

### My structure project:

```
Projet
- backend
-- DockerFile
- frontend
-- DockerFile

docker-compose
```

### Backend DockerFile

```
FROM node:14.17
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

### Frontend DockerFile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN npm install -g http-server
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./Backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    networks:
      - backend_net
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./Frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    networks:
      - backend_net
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=p07_social_network
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    networks:
      - backend_net
networks:
  backend_net:
    name: p07_network
```

### My network inspect

```
[
    {
        "Name": "p07_network",
        "Id": "1114316946c08de4b3e7b966517e1bcb8e6cfe4d56d0bbad9dce5b67d1dddbf1",
        "Created": "2021-05-31T19:29:59.8465635Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.28.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.28.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2f1a7dc4151d13a374d10fd810b0155e07d1694837e57a6aacba8b97e06336a4": {
                "Name": "leonfrederic_7_07032021_mysqldb_1",
                "EndpointID": "d8480cf00d627de83f1524bb1433d4f6be262c5b9848a38ff7da85e4cefdb0df",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "5a5f54be579538982bdbf35b1c5be60465a080bb8c8abc5584e27c64968b5dd7": {
                "Name": "leonfrederic_7_07032021_backend_1",
                "EndpointID": "43385ee40f09c497b1aaf54c691493a3d25efcb9ecfb6f08a3e08e34a6870e71",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e55cf7bd076f8e34901a039f5159450856b25d2186c1137d052438ded27329d3": {
                "Name": "leonfrederic_7_07032021_frontend_1",
                "EndpointID": "2712002e92f69b916dfd298ffa85cadbb9d785e35473d9825e7d65df5db84546",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1c:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.28.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "p07_network",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "leonfrederic_7_07032021",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.1"
        }
    }
]
```

Edit: I install a virtual linux and i have the same probleme. So i'm lost ^^

Comment: remove ```volumes``` on frontend docker-compose.yml.

Comment: @jiholee Thx for your help, It's change nothing :'(

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. You need to publish server from localhost to 0.0.0.0 in Dockerfile.

## Frontend

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:14.16.1
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/


RUN rm yarn.lock
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

Then you can go localhost:8080/ to see the web browser result.